# c# XML to linq error if null

Tags: c#, xml, linq, converters

I have a `method` that is parsing an `XML` file.

My method is:

```
public static List<UpperLevelGPS> ParseXml(string Document) 
 {
            List<UpperLevelGPS> result = new List<UpperLevelGPS>();
            result.Clear();                                     

            doc = XDocument.Load(Document);

            result = (from n in doc.Descendants("level")
                      select new UpperLevelGPS()
                      {
                          CurrentLevel = int.Parse(n.Attribute("CurrentLevel").Value),

                          TeleNodes = (from l in n.Element("UpperLevelGPSs").Elements("UpperLevelGPS")
                                       select new TeleNodes()
                                       {
                                           id = (int)(l.Attribute("id")),
                                           UpperLevelGPSMapID = (int)l.Attribute("UpperLevelGPSMapID"),
                                           DestinationMapID = (int)l.Attribute("DestinationMapID"),
                                           HostelID = (int)l.Attribute("HostelID"),
                                           x = (float)l.Attribute("x"),
                                           y = (float)l.Attribute("y"),
                                           z = (float)l.Attribute("z")
                                       }).ToList()
                      }).ToList();

            return result;
}
```

Node `UpperLevelGPSs` won't allways exists in my `XML` file, so above `query` fails. How can i catch and handle `null` event?

Comment: How about using a ternary operator `?` ? `a != null ? (int)a : 0;`

Comment: Can you please show how its done in my code?

Comment: Oh i see i made a mistake in my question. I meant node `UpperLevelGPSs` is the one that wont allways exists.

Comment: Just do `from l in n.Elements("UpperLevelGPSs").Elements("UpperLevelGPS")`.  If `UpperLevelGPSs` you'll get an empty `TeleNodes` list.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it does before the linq statment:

```
public static List<UpperLevelGPS> ParseXml(string Document) 
    {
            List<UpperLevelGPS> result = new List<UpperLevelGPS>();
            result.Clear();                                     

            doc = XDocument.Load(Document);

            var upperLevelGPSs = n.Element("UpperLevelGPSs");

            if (upperLevelGPSs.Count > 0)
            {
                result = (from n in doc.Descendants("level")
                            select new UpperLevelGPS()
                            {
                                CurrentLevel = int.Parse(n.Attribute("CurrentLevel").Value),

                                TeleNodes = (from l in upperLevelGPSs .Elements("UpperLevelGPS")
                                            select new TeleNodes()
                                            {
                                                id = (int)(l.Attribute("id")),
                                                UpperLevelGPSMapID = (int)l.Attribute("UpperLevelGPSMapID"),
                                                DestinationMapID = (int)l.Attribute("DestinationMapID"),
                                                HostelID = (int)l.Attribute("HostelID"),
                                                x = (float)l.Attribute("x"),
                                                y = (float)l.Attribute("y"),
                                                z = (float)l.Attribute("z")
                                            }).ToList()
                            }).ToList();
            }
            return result;
}
```

Note: I have not tested this.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                   {
                                       id = (int)(l.Attribute("id")),
                                       UpperLevelGPSMapID = (int?)l.Attribute("UpperLevelGPSMapID"),
                                       DestinationMapID = (int)l.Attribute("DestinationMapID"),
                                       HostelID = (int)l.Attribute("HostelID"),
                                       x = (float)l.Attribute("x"),
                                       y = (float)l.Attribute("y"),
                                       z = (float)l.Attribute("z")
                                   }).ToList()
                  }).ToList();
```

(Int?) Will result in null value if attribute in not present.